# Why the index template hide application template elements in emberJS app

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a index.html like folows

```
<body>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
            <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2>
                 {{outlet}}
      </script>
      <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
            <h2> Welcome to index</h2>
      </script> 
</body>
```

In browser, I see only "Welcome to index" why not

Welcome to Ember.js
Welcome to index

My route related code is

```
App.Router.map(function() {
 // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ });
```

My view related code is

```
App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
templateName:'index'
});
```

I use the following js

```
     head.load("css/style.css",
            "js/libs/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js",
            "js/libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js",
            "js/libs/jquery/jquery.sizes.js",
            "js/libs/jlayout/jlayout.border.js",
            "js/libs/jlayout/jquery.jlayout.js",
            "js/libs/jquery/mutate/mutate.events.js",
            "js/libs/jquery/mutate/mutate.js",
            "js/libs/handlebars-1.3.0.js",
            "js/libs/ember/ember-1.6.1.js",
            "js/app.js",
            "js/views/applicationView.js"
    );
```

I have seen that if I have removed 
        templateName:'index' 
from
        App.ApplicationView
the index template have not remmoved the application template elements but throw a bug

```
   DEBUG: -------------------------------
   DEBUG: Ember      : 1.6.1
   DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
   DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
   DEBUG: -------------------------------
   debug:
   generated -> route:application Object { fullName="route:application"}
   generated -> route:index Object { fullName="route:index"}
   generated -> controller:application Object { fullName="controller:application"}
   Rendering application with <App.ApplicationView:ember212> Object {
              fullName="view:application"}
   generated -> controller:index Object { fullName="controller:index"}
   Rendering index with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember228> Object {
              fullName="view:index"}
   Transitioned into 'index'
   TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
   document.getElementById( this.morph.start ).parentNode === 
   ember-1.6.1.js (line 32241)
```

Comment: Can we see your external JS links please?  How are you creating your Ember app?

Comment: Could you post your router?

Comment: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/putineju/1/edit

Comment: Why `data-template-name` instead of `id` attribute for `application` ?

Comment: App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here

});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ });

Comment: I have added the route

 kingpin2k 2 in [http://emberjs.jsbin.com/joyiqute/1/edit] "Welcome to Ember.js" was not seen but in [http://emberjs.jsbin.com/putineju/1/edit] the difference is the IndexRoute which I have also used but no result